# Is this 'that' a pronoun or a conjunctive?

Tags: relative-pronouns, conjunctions

> . . . frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile
>   levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate
>   revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelation
>   of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are
>   usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving
>   judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of
>   missing something if I forget **that**, as my father snobbishly
>   suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental
>   decencies is parceled out unequally at birth. (F. Scott Fitzgerald,
>   The Great Gatsby)

Is ‘that’ a pronoun that referring to any words or that-clause is a noun clause and object of ‘forget’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out *as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat*, and you will see that it’s a subordinator, introducing the clause *a sense of the fundamental decencies is parceled out unequally at birth*.