# Conjunction vs Subordinator vs Subordinating conjunction

Tags: terminology

The answer to https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5236/8712 includes only 'subordinator'. Yet What are the similarities and differences between these three? Is there a hierachy?

https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subordinate.html says:

> CONJUNCTION ... secondary class called SUBORDINATING or SUBORDINATE conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional grammar regarded such terms as *and, or, but, that, if* as **conjunctions**—particles which ‘join’ two elements of the sentence. In this theory, conjunctions are of two sorts: coordinating conjunctions, which join elements at the same syntactic ‘level’, and subordinating conjunctions, which join an element at a ‘lower’ level to one at a ‘higher’ level.

Many contemporary grammarians—for instance, the authors of the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language—discard the metaphor which imagines that these words serve a single function, that of ‘joining’ elements, and they consequently discard the term ‘conjunction’, which unites them in the same category. Instead, these grammarians employ different terms to designate different functions: *and* and *or* are called **coordinators**, while *that*, *for* and *if* are called **subordinators**.